# login to remote using “mstsc /admin” with password

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, remote-desktop

I want to use mstsc /admin to login to a server silently.
My batch file reads the code as

```
set mysrvad=server_ip
set mysrvid=id
set mysrvpswd=pw


cmdkey /generic:%mysrvad% /user:%mysrvid% /pass:%mysrvpswd%
cls
mstsc.exe /v:%mysrvad%
exit
```

You are still prompted to enter your password.
Help me

Comment: create an `rdp` file :)

Comment: What @Gerhard said, although group policy may prevent the use of saved passwords.

Comment: The ID and password will be entered from the user.
Is there any way other than making an RDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unfortunately unable to even test this right now as I am not in the position to remote to any Windows devices in my current environment, but this is the idea:

```
@echo off
set "mysrvad=10.1.2.3"
set /p "mysrvid=enter username: "
set /p "mysrvpswd=Enter Password: "
for /f "delims=" %%p in ('powershell -command "(\"%mysrvpswd%\" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) | ConvertFrom-SecureString;"') do set "encry=%%p"
(for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ("%mysrvad% %mysrvid%") do (
    echo full address:s:%%~i
    echo username:s:%%~j
    echo password 51:b:%encry%
 )
)>%mysrvad%.rdp
start "" mstsc.exe %mysrvad%.rdp
```

Some explanations:

As you should be aware by testing `set /p` prompts user input for both username and password and saves them into variables. The first `for` loop runs a `powershell` command to create an encrypted password and then adds it to the `rdp` file. You can see what the `rdp` file looks like by browsing to the directory where the script is located and then editing the `rdp` file in that folder using notepad. alternatively you can open `cmd` then `cd` to the location and do `type nameoffile.rdp`

Before I get to the final `for` loop. let me explain the `delims=` and some basic for loop functions.

a for loop works as such:
`for` each item `in` (item/s to do stuff for) `do` something.
This by default will take a given string and then split it by some `delim`iters such as whitespace, comma, semicolon etc.

With the `powershell` `for` loop example, we need to run `/f` because we are launching a command where we can to extract the output of that command. and so be sure that we do not use any default delimiter to split the string so that we capture the entire line and assign it to the metavariable `%%p`

lastly, the final for loop. We take the two created variables for server and user and we add them as the items in the `for` loop to work with. `tokens=1,2*` is based on the word position in the default delimiter here, being whitespace. This allows us to assign the first word as first `token` and word 2 as the second. meaning `%%i` is `server` and `%%j` is `user`. We simply add the earlier created variable for the encrypted password to the list and then we redirect everything as output to a file, which in this case will be the server name, or ip as you added in `mysrvad`.

When the loops has done what it needed, it is done and we simply launch `mstsc.exe` with the rdp file.

obviously this is just a minimal explanation to what is happening here, but you can open `cmd` and then run `for /?` to see most of the help needed to understand `for` loops and its functions.

Comment: As soon as I checked, I tested it.
It's a really nice code.
I don't understand from the delims, but thank you.

Comment: added some explanations for you.